# "Por volta de" ou "cerca de"

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

Olá.

Gostaria de saber se **por volta de** e **cerca de** têm o mesmo sentido.

Por exemplo, nos seguintes casos, um pode ser substituído pelo outro?

> Finalmente irá para o Sul, onde ficará cerca de cinco dias.
>
> Ela dis que o médico virá por volta das 17h.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As expressões são próximas, mas *por volta de* é mais usada com pontos/instantes e *cerca de* com durações e outras quantidades.

> O espetáculo terminou *por volta* / *cerca* das duas da manhã.
>   Ele chegou *por volta* / *cerca* da hora de jantar.
>   As primeiras batatas são colhidas *por volta* / ?*cerca* de Abril.
>   Apercebi-me do problema *por volta* / ?*cerca* de 1998.
>   O primeiro golo foi marcado *por volta* / ?*cerca* da marca dos 15 minutos.
>   Garcia tomou o comando da corrida *por volta* / ?*cerca* da marca dos 20 km.

Com horas, *cerca* é perfeitamente aceitável (ainda que preferisse *por volta de*), mas os outros casos parecem-me mais marginais.

Com durações, *cerca* parece-me uma melhor opção, talvez por frequentemente ser precedido de outra preposição, mas *por volta* também é possível.

> Conheço-o há *cerca* / *por volta* de dois anos.
>   Entreteve-se a «brincar» com a bola durante *cerca* / *por volta* de 15 minutos.
>   Vou-me encontrar com ele dentro de *cerca* / *por volta* de 15 minutos.

Com outras quantidades, *cerca* é também preferível:

> Residem na vila *cerca* / *por volta* de dois mil habitantes.
>   A notícia foi mal recebida pelos *cerca* / ?*por volta* de 600 barcos espanhóis.
>   Estão aqui atracados *cerca* / *por volta* de 600 barcos.

Parece-me difícil dizer *pelos por volta de*. Novamente, a existência de uma preposição parece-me favorecer *cerca*.

Answer (score 2):

As duas expressões são equivalentes e não vejo nenhuma diferença entre as expressões "por volta de cinco dias" ou "cerca de cinco dias", às quais eu acrescentaria ainda "uns cinco dias" e "mais ou menos cinco dias". São todas equivalentes quando nos referimos a *quantidades aproximadas*.

O segundo exemplo não se refere a uma quantidade, mas a um momento específico. Nesse caso, eu diria apenas "por volta das 17h", "umas 17h" ou "mais ou menos às 17h", mas **não usaria** o "cerca de".